# django encode UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, django

I have a problem in django project.

UnicodeEncodeError at /contact/1/view 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 28: ordinal not in range(128)

in Traceback: views.py in single_contact

```
'vcard_str': unicode(VCard(contact)),
```

and all view

```
def single_contact(request, pk):
    contact = Contact.objects.get(pk = pk)
    if contact.group.user != request.user.profile:
        raise Http404
    if request.method=="GET":
        emails = Email.objects.filter(contact = contact)
        hash = ''
        if emails:
            email = emails[0]
            hash = get_hash(email.email)
        addresses = Address.objects.filter(contact = contact)
        if addresses:
            address = addresses[0]
        phones = PhoneNumber.objects.filter(contact=contact)
        return render(request,'dashboard/addressbook/single_contact.html',
            RequestContext(request, {
                'contact':contact, 'emails':emails, 'hash':hash,
                'addresses':addresses, 'phones':phones,
                'vcard_str': unicode(VCard(contact)),
            }))
    elif request.method=="POST":
        contact.delete()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('addressbook_index'))
    else:
        raise Http404
```

but if i change sting

```
'vcard_str': unicode(VCard(contact)),
```

to

```
'vcard_str':  VCard(contact).encode("utf-8")
```

i got another error:
AttributeError at /contact/1/view

```
VCard object has no attribute encode
```

what i'm doing wrong ? how can i fix this?

Comment: Why are you calling `unicode` on this object at all?

Comment: And what is `VCard` anyway ???

Comment: VCard - class in helper.py (part of my app)

Comment: you might want to check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20

Comment: if i dont call unicode - i got an error UnicodeEncodeError at /contact/1/view 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 28-33: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Read the  answers on the link I added above, you will get more understanding as to why you get that error.

Comment: You should show the full traceback for the error to her when you don't call unicode.

Comment: UnicodeDecodeError at /contact/2/view

'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 170: ordinal not in range(128)


its same error. if i call str or unicode or encode